# Sencha touch animation problem - after slide animation is completed it is still present on the screen

Tags: sencha-touch

Here is my animation code:

```
 Ext.Anim.run(loginform, 'slide', {
                                        out: true,
                                        direction: 'left',
                                        autoClear: false
                                                });
```

And here is my loginform:

```
loginform = new Ext.form.FormPanel({ 
    url: 'login.php',
    standardSubmit : false,
    style: 'margin-top: 60px',
    items: [...]
```

And in relation to the page:

```
myapp.cards.home = new Ext.Panel({
        scroll: 'vertical',
        id: "home-card",
        layout:{
            type:"vbox",
            align:"center"
        },
        items: [header, loginform]
    });
```

The animation code is ran on successful submit of the form. However after loginform slides to the left it doesn't completely dissapear off the screen.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to update your sencha version with the new one !

Comment: I am using the latest version.